# Rigify Only made the Face rig

Tags: rigify

[image: a picture of the 'generated rig' (after aligning it better)]So I aligned a rigify meta-rig with my character's entire body (including his face) but when I generate a rig it only creates a facial rig and none of the rest of the body, I have no clue why, thanks.

Comment: On closer inspection the face rig doesn't appear as it should, it has made a bunch of empty circles around every vertex in the bones but none of the standard controllers that I notice in tutorials

Comment: Are you able to update the post with screenshots of the results your getting?

Comment: Okay, I hope that helps to clarify my problem.